How Come My UV Image Projection by perspective doesn't match with image?
I am trying to model a cake box with an image texture with perspective, however, when mapping, the top plane gets distorted for some strange reason.
Original Image with mesh object shown in wireframe mode:

Uv editor view:

What it looks like on render (Notice how the top plane is distorted)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You could try inserting a few edge loops or subdividing the box a few times. UV Mapping may work better with denser geometry in Blender.

Tried subdividing but still no luck. First time trying to project textures by perspective and it's so weird

Have you subdivided now after projecting the UV map? First subdivide the mesh, then do the projection mapping. And it also depends on how many subdividions you have, more is better.
